# Character encoding error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using asp.net pages with master page and getting error:

> The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared.
>   The document will render with garbled text in some browser
>   configurations if the document contains characters from outside the
>   US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be
>   declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order
>   mark as an encoding signature

If master page is not apply on the content page then page working fine.
Please provide some solution for this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Check : [How to: Select an Encoding for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39d1w2xf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

you need to specify the encoding for the all page like this

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization
      fileEncoding="utf-8"
      requestEncoding="utf-8"
      responseEncoding="utf-8"
      culture="en-US"
      uiCulture="de-DE"
    />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

or

for the page

```
<%@ Page RequestEncoding="utf-8" ResponseEncoding="utf-8" %>
```